# jQuery: How to select an option in select box based on option's HTML text?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

To get the text of the selected option I do:

```
$("select option:selected").text()
```

How could I set an option based on it's text ?

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADp6L/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
 $('select option:contains("C")').attr('selected', true);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ADp6L/1/

Comment: I like how clean this solution is.  Just make sure that none of your options will contain text that is a substring of another option or you might get false positives.  Will :contains take a regex by chance?

Answer (score 4):

Clear the old selection out first and then loop through the options, canceling the loop once the correction option is found.

```
$("select option").removeAttr("selected").each(function() {
    var jThis = $(this);

    if (jThis.text() == "mytext") {
        jThis.attr("selected", "selected");
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: +1 for supplying an alternative that eliminates false positives.



I made a fiddle for this alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/HFnb7/